# JavaScript failing on page postback

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have got this script to give effects to buttons which i have, it fails after the page is posted back, i have also put the code in a pageLoad method yet it still does not function. any idea how i can go about making this script run once the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

            /*preloader for image loading bar*/

            jQuery(function ($) {
                function preLoad() {
                    //alert("script running");
                    $("#divQuestionMatrix").addClass("hidden");
                }

                function loaded() {
                    $("#divQuestionMatrix").removeClass("hidden");
                    $('div#preLoader').css({ display: 'none' }).remove();
                }

                preLoad();
                window.onload = loaded;
            });

            /* End of preloader*/



            $("#btnPrevious").click(function (e) {
                $("#navigation").val("previous");
            }
            );
            $("#btnNext").click(function (e) {
                $("#navigation").val("next");
            }
            );

            /* $(".qmatrix").click(function () {
            //get id of button
            alert($(this).attr('id'));
            $("#navigation").val($(this).attr('id'));
            }
            );*/

            $(".qmatrix").hover(function (e) {
                //get id of button
                //alert($(this).attr('id'));
                //get src of image before hover
                var origimage = $(this).attr('src');
                // alert(origimage);
                //$(this).attr({ src: 'images/questionMatrix/100' + $(this).attr('id') + '.png' });
                $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "0.1" }, "fast")
            },
            function () {
                // $(this).attr({ src: '' + origimage.toString() + '' });
                $(this).stop().animate({ "opacity": "1" }, "fast");
            }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `document.ready` event is fired once the page has finished loading.

Inside the handler for the ready event, you're then using the ready event shortcut (passing a function directly to the global jQuery function (which is the same as the global `$` function btw) to add another handler function for the ready event.

Inside this second ready handler you're then trying to assign the loaded function to `window.onload`, which would have already fired by this point.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Put this Latest Jquery Library Just just above to your `document.ready()` function and try to run your program.